# Using scanf to create new struct object

Tags: c, struct, scanf

Hi I'm using to create a simple program that contains a list of Users (based on the struct below), and I'm trying to create new users based on user input, where I ask for each property seperately using `scanf`. But I'm having trouble with the structs limitations, for example id should be at max 10 chars and nome can have a max of 25 chars. Here's my code for more context:

```
struct user {
  char id[10];
  char name[25];
  char group;
  float score;
};

struct user list[25];
int registered = 0;

void createNewUser() {
  struct user *userPtr, newUser;
  userPtr = &newUser;

  printf("\nId: ");
  scanf("%10s", &(*userPtr).id);
  printf("\nName: ");
  scanf("%25s", &(*userPtr.name);
  printf("\nGroup: ");
  scanf("%c", &(*userPtr).group);
  printf("\nScore: ");
  scanf("%f", &(*userPtr).score);

  insert(newUser);

  printf("%10s\n", list[0].id);
  printf("%25s\n", list[0].name);
  printf("%c\n", list[0].group);
  printf("%.1f\n", list[0].score);
}

void insert(struct user newUser) {
  if (registered < 25){
    list[registered] = newUser;
    registered += 1;
  }
}
```

With the code I presented above, if I type more than 10 chars for the first input, the next 2 are ignored. And my 3rd scanf is always ignored, the one for group. Can anyone here help me out with this?

Comment: regarding: `struct user *userPtr, newUser;`  this puts the 'newUser' on the stack.  It should be via dynamic memory I.E. on the heap, via a call to `malloc()` or `calloc()`.  Otherwise, it is corrupted (and undefined behavior) when the function: `createNewUser()` is exited.

Comment: regarding: scanf("%10s", &(*userPtr).id);` (and similar statements)  the input format specifier: '%s' always appends a NUL byte to the input, so the MAX Characters modifier (I.E the 10) should be 1 less than the length of the input buffer (I.E. it should be 9)

Comment: In C, when an array is referenced via its' name alone, then the array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  so this line: `scanf("%10s", &(*userPtr).id);` should be: `scanf( "%9s",  userPtr->id );`.  Similar considerations exist for the other arrays in the struct

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%c", &(*userPtr).group);`  the leading 'white space' needs to be consumed/skipped over.  Suggest: `scanf( " %c", &userPtr->group );`.  Notice the leading space in the format string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `scanf` is that when it stops converting characters and there are
more in the input buffer (because the user entered more than you anticipated), then `scanf` will leave those characters there.
Specially the newline character (inputed when the user presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)
remains in the input buffer, which causes problems to subsequent calls of
`scanf` that read characters or strings. So in this case you have to "clean" the input buffer,
so that the next `scanf` does not consume the left overs of the previous `scanf` calls.

You can use this function after every `scanf`:

```
void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
printf("\nId: ");
scanf("%10s", (*userPtr).id); // no need for &, id is char[]
clean_stdin();

printf("\nName: ");
scanf("%25s", (*userPtr).name); // same here
clean_stdin();

printf("\nGroup: ");
scanf("%c", &(*userPtr).group);
clean_stdin();

printf("\nScore: ");
scanf("%f", &(*userPtr).score);
```

Also note that the way you are if the maximal length of the ID is 10, then the
buffer must be of length 11, because in C you need to terminate the strings with
the `'\0'`-terminating byte. So change your structure to this:

```
struct user {
  char id[11];
  char name[26];
  char group;
  float score;
};
```

Also bear in mind, using a pointer like this

```
struct user *userPtr, newUser;
  userPtr = &newUser;

  printf("\nId: ");
  scanf("%10s", (*userPtr).id);
  ...
```

is not necessary, it actually makes the code harder to read. You can do:

```
void createNewUser() {
    struct user newUser;

    printf("\nId: ");
    scanf("%10s", newUser.id);
    clean_stdin();
    ...

    printf("\nScore: ");
    scanf("%f", &newUser.score);
    ...
}
```

Comment: @chux I know, that's why I suggested to change the struct itself, `id` and `name` are 11 and 26 instead of 10 and 25.